# Allow http access only from two selected IPs and get alerts for other attempted logins

Tags: security, apache-http-server, logging, htaccess

we want a system where our server can be accessed only by 2 selected systems. Also we need to log any other attempted access.

One possible option we have is:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from <your ip>
```

Is there any other solution better than this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, use a firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is sound.  As appleodity said, you could also use a firewall (but in this case your solution is better because it will have more accurate logging).

You might want to couple this with fail2ban which monitors log files and can be used to email you and/or implement a firewall block on multiple attempts from the same IP.